# Block all PWA's in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to block the installation and execution of PWA's in Chrome.

I installed the group policy template hoping to find a setting in there. The closest one is [WebAppSettings](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=WebAppSettings) and I have 2 issues:

1. It's not clear from the documentation whether it will actually prevent PWA's from running after login
2. It's not clear how to enter a multiline value into a single line field. I tried removing all the newlines, but nothing happened. PWA's could be run just like before.